# Missing numbers in nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Good day, For example: If I have an nsarray [3, 1, -5, 3, 3, -5, 0, 1, 1, 3]
How do I calculate Missing numbers in my Array:
-4
-3
-2
-1
2
But -  No sorting is allowed and must run in linear time O(N)

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Well the brute force way would be something like this

a. find the max and min values in the array -5, 3

b. loop multiple times the array form -5 to 3 looking for the specific number (-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0 .... 3)

b1. if the number if found break that loop and continue with the next

b2 . if the loop ends without breaking take note of that number

It's inefficient compared to just sorting it, but it runs in a linear way

Comment: for (i = -5; i < 4; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < array.count ; j++ {
    if (array[j] == i) {
      //break here
    }
  }
  // if not found mark number as missing here
}

something like this

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to make another array of bools and to check true if that number exist. After you do that, just go through array of bools and if number is false then its missing.

Answer (score 1):

plz use this code

```
   NSArray *a = @[@3, @1, @-5, @3, @3, @-5, @0, @1, @1, @3];

    NSNumber *max=[a valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
    NSNumber *min=[a valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"];

    int big = [max intValue];
    int small = [min intValue];

    while (small<=big) {

        if ([a containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:small]]) {

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"missing number is %d",small);
        }




        small++;
    }

 result
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good, however you can make it more concise: `for (int num = min + 1; num < max; num++) { ... }` (note `+1` and `<` as you don't need to check if `min` and `max` are there).  Then you can drop `small` and `big`.

Comment: This will be O(n^2) since `containsObject` iterates the array looking for a match

Comment: @Paulw11 this answer is right or not ? what mean of  O(n^2) since.

Comment: It doesn't run in O(n) as worst case it iterates the array for each element In the array. This means that it is O n squared O(n^2). At first glance it appears linear but containsObject isn't magic. It has to loop through the array, so hidden in that `containsObject` is another loop

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in the array are consecutive integers, then 'Sort' the array and find the difference between the two consecutive numbers. If it is 1, then the number is not missed. Else, the number has missed.

Comment: No sorting is allowed

Comment: Then, find the maximum and minimum value in the array. Then find the intermediate values whether they are present or missing. This requires the complexity of 'n'